# Recursive Type Mapping in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to extract a type mapping from an object containing native type validation function so for example, if I have the object

```
const test  = {
  Test: {
    Test1: {
      Test2: SimpleStringValidator //return type is string or undefined but input can be anything
    },
  }
}
```

I want to extract the type

```
type Extracted = {
  Test: {
    Test1: {
      Test2: string
    }
  }
}
```

Towards this end I wrote the following code to extract the return types of an object containing a set of nested validation functions

Sample.ts

```
export type Validator<T> = NativeTypeValidator<T> | ObjectValidator<T>

export type NativeTypeValidator<T> = (n: any) => T | undefined
export type ObjectValidator<O> = {
  [K in keyof O]: Validator<O[K]> 
}

//native validators
export const SimpleStringValidator:NativeTypeValidator<string> = (val) => typeof(val) === "string" ? val : undefined

//object validator function
export const ObjValidator = <V>(validatorObj: ObjectValidator<V>) => (o:any):V =>{
  let result = {} as V;
  //we can only validate objects
  if (typeof (o) !== "object") { return undefined; }
  const validatorKeys = Object.keys(o) as [keyof ObjectValidator<V>]
  validatorKeys.forEach((validatorKey) => { 
    const objValue = o[validatorKey] as V[keyof V];
    const objectValidator = validatorObj[validatorKey]
    if (!objectValidator) { return undefined } //do nothing if no validator exists for the key in o
    //figure out if we have a nested object validator or a native validator at the corresponding key of validatorObj
    if (typeof (objectValidator) === "object") {
      result[validatorKey] = ObjValidator(objectValidator as ObjectValidator<V[keyof V]>)(objValue)
    }
    else {
      const nativeValidator = objectValidator as NativeTypeValidator<V[keyof V]>;
      result[validatorKey] = nativeValidator(objValue)
    }
  })
  return result;
}

export const test  = {
  Test: {
    Test1: {
      Test2: SimpleStringValidator
    },
  }
}

export const validatorFunc = ObjValidator(test);
export const outputExample = validatorFunc({
  Test: {
    Test1: {
      Test2: "hi"
    },
  }
})

outputExample.Test.Test1.Test2 = "1";
outputExample.Test.Test1.Test2 = 1; //vs code intellisense complains because needs to be type string
```

In my case intellisense  auto-completes the nested property Test2 and has the type as string but when I create the type declaration files the type information is different and I can't export this generated type to other projects correctly. Specifically it sets the type of property Test1 to any. The type I'm looking to generate is the output of validatorFunc and the type of outputExample in the code above.

Generated sample.d.ts

```
export declare type Validator<T> = NativeTypeValidator<T> | ObjectValidator<T>;
export declare type NativeTypeValidator<T> = (n: any) => T | undefined;
export declare type ObjectValidator<O> = {
    [K in keyof O]: Validator<O[K]>;
};
export declare const SimpleStringValidator: NativeTypeValidator<string>;
export declare const ObjValidator: <V>(validatorObj: ObjectValidator<V>) => (o: any) => V;
export declare const test: {
    Test: {
        Test1: {
            Test2: NativeTypeValidator<string>;
        };
    };
};
export declare const validatorFunc: (o: any) => {
    Test: {
        Test1: any;
    };
};
export declare const outputExample: {
    Test: {
        Test1: any;
    };
};
```

I need to use the root validator object as the source for my extracted type looking for a solution where the generated declaration file has the correct type. I have this code up on Typescript playground and it shows the difference between autocomplete and what gets put into the .d.ts file.

[TypescriptPlayground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=false&experimentalDecorators=false&target=6&jsx=0&ts=4.0.0-beta#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAjgTwiBA1AhgGwJYAmWcsAPACoB8CAvAgHLF4BuI5qI2%20RJMF1AHwQB5AEYArEAGM4XQsTJVgoSLEQo0DJq3Zo5PRdToAKAHYAuBFlPIAlLWrkEQgK6mCIAGZ5TIAiuh4JA4RCWlZXHleUmEjBABvYAQEAG0AaQQfBABrEGQoTxEAXUt9BT5hdKLqYABfZQB6BtNtdGZIgxgAZwC1BCkoUy7EAGU8AFsIHBARuBgfAHMy3nNGOBY2DmWyYfnTBbjjdpx7GmoNEAKj3FOaOgAiXcX7hAB%20BGOESzcPb19-YBNBBNKBhGQfDrlBCeNwyPCDXpBAZDRBicTbGC0BCkDCUa7ccpoyxo8IYnGUU7UYxQczWOzmDAORLJaaIGAgLouHCIOjxWpWLqYADcSWBDQA7ugpNYEIMcMgIQS4OhQZIZD1knhCsYLgUENT7ABCO4Ie6q8L3ezxBDsuAuGCmBA-Lw%20PxChD1ZLI4aKqKwNJ5QV0EkyAB0uWQXQNAtSEb1IYiSrIuKKouOfpgAcjoc8sAAolgpAALYz4jNZykJBCir2DH2qrgudB0KApdOdLNFGMYFJxwoYIoi5K1lGysGJjNY9uEiRtyG8Ts1zLaw3mmQYq02kB2h1O9wu-4esUEKAIUxQOBFxbLs%20n6e8BDgPDDQW5zGX9ARzKOqBLpreBZ7RVFxEC1BBJQQIssFYKwzw5ZUCDHNVEHvWBZUxLAz1aX1OisdQiylWB2S6aB3GvL89VQmA0SXMCdQ4PVqXHDdaBNM1x0tBIl2SYiuTgOck0zPIu2DCQMSY5CMRjBMyR7PtMGqWwJMbEBbCXT1hxAHAunQZlhxHH0WnWVgpJbZj5zQrBBTWDZdE4Cy%20DkvI9QHSgh30rdOW5ATy2ErEjI2cSG1wJs1P0jTajCrcd0dXjuRFepEUQb11Hg5JeVFch4MsPTkiy4YAEYcu4hB8rgAAmSwxkmaZZj2JYHPUgAaUV6kS8BAmSusUIcgAxWEsTRcTlWGWwRQ6voUtlECIBAvMwCwGrmxw8p%20tMKRjD0sriv0sqiq4jzSvgyrTSve5mtauo1OAKAZrmhaltDMqnvggqXuGcqsXuAr7hFW64FmuB5sWqYQHeuBwbesrProAr3SaZhBQGDxv2VHB8B0oZCJqrAfEFURpCwFwdLgvxBRIBACeCTQfDgYAgA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to extract:

```
{
  Test: {
    Test1: {
      Test2: string
    }
  }
}
```

You can use this recursive type mapping, using `infer`:

```
type ValidatedObject<T> = Partial<{
  [key in keyof T]: T[key] extends ObjectValidator<infer Type>
    ? ValidatedObject<Type>
    : T[key] extends NativeTypeValidator<infer Type>
    ? Type
    : T[key] extends object
    ? ValidatedObject<T[key]>
    : T[key];
}>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=false&experimentalDecorators=false&target=6&jsx=0&ts=4.0.0-beta&ssl=41&ssc=7&pln=42&pc=28#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBqBDANgSwCYYzQA8AKgHxwC8cpcoMwAdngM5wQBGAVsAMbwA-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-VrOiC+ACEbOBFZgwN8JTgYZgwSgTEF8OFMTTcBGFQ18FlFOqzXYNBTMAAdE1EKwXb4E1V1w3l-d-e1M7OMvONyvwtAAKIYPgACxcNrlUHPTp7manq01BSkwVQNAQJUp6yOe7TxomlR7m0aDtBmFRfuiHCpJIXryjQIHQPawFoa+zTHghdS1s2Hb3N2vbAP2g7DgiIoTlmeAQHATAQDA96nERzFMZhUDZDg6zsFevFsag651EOECflmkQnAO5bBPANZwLmcD3hgmjxsx4beshhQzrhHC8RgzFTKWtqyPGiT3nm0BhqwkAsBxYkNjx9pSUpLj8QeuH+i6KFkd2UkVHZkYwDh5nQGBur2vcfl6WRcV-sA27sBa8EIZOCHAFgrCoEGhGot+8CTNcmg6oB-kGTuaVBRREZRuFL5RTQJU3LFv7YP+KXxl46UVJlQzeJmfYDkOIVRhmmaKkwyqrHUrDeRFcgGgwzDGh21o8R4XgemZL7zVqEiHmggZSSN1H1m0PGsiCHbAulIwjEYPwmuZyYofIuoAAoYLAODYMQ+VQc04mNM0DakJ0tDA4g4GrXk1ilbc9g+VE4TALxpLkFJwiklJSikDDcM5Gt7CLS+xBoxjtA6NjhHCEmPofVj+PQ+uxNGvkKE469czvXpZBE3TCEE0TGZDNjarLEVCDabq+WkNpSj5RUivrAAjMrtVqzAABMShbLs+yHE8Zy4QANNr2kAMwG5i+y4lyhIW1JQyW-1wwmGYKLTntFIAGJKtFPCxYw6zeBm3vqjLEAKWACnXiAGBGwBfsZIHM0uArSulFJOua7nBW0Np+vsuxwKu+7E7DENRixzA8cwInydYiuOtt9p6sd+suu6sC6v3XXccJ0nKfd6u+fj73NDq+O4zqOwKzwuJjBYLguVrDZRsYFE7CcPwGDBLlWkxOwRBwPvljJFEMBGEAA)

> Note: The partial is there for two reasons, one is that the type is outputted fully to the *.d.ts* file and the other is the `undefined` return value.

Comment: Thanks for this, I had a feeling infer would play into this answer. My actual use case is a bit more complicated so I'm taking this answer and the playgroud example and trying to add support for Arrays. I really am liking typescript but it can get pretty complicated pretty quickly at which point rather than writing simple javascript I'm fighting with satisfying exotic type mappings of my own doing.

Comment: One question, if I change my simple validator from using a string generic to a boolean or a number this no longer works.  I expected this would work for both number and boolean but clearly it appears that I am wrong about that.

Comment: @MacD, Apparently TypeScript decided to match anything but `string`s to `ObjectValidator`, I updated the definition and it works correctly now (TS Playground link in answer updated)

Comment: Thank you, your Typescript skills are awesome. Any recommendations on how to learn to tune typescript like you did in this example or better troubleshoot it when you have a problem. None of these answers are particularly obvious and it is hard to maintain something that is fragile and to a  large degree unintuitive (at least to me and my level of proficiency so far) especially in a shared code base where you have a wide range of Typescript proficiency among developers.

Comment: @MacD, My Advice would be two things, firstly is to understand how these types work (in this case recursion) since you have a limited set of tools at your disposal, which you have to combine to tell typescript what you want. My other advice would be to define your types before writing functions and making sure your generics are as narrow as possible. PS: a small bonus tip, if you use Utility Types typescript fully evaluates your type in .d.ts and itelisense.